# VS2013 cannot import settings from TOOLS>Import and Export Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was trying to import some settings to VS2013, but after a few steps the wizard window just disappears when I click Next. The wizard is closed and does nothing.

*TOOLS > Import and Export Settings > Import selected environment settings>No just import new settings, overwrite my current settings;*
press Next here, 
the window just goes away, triggering no action.

In fact all options under Import selected environment settings does nothing; the wizard window just goes away without triggering any action.

I tried export settings it work fine.

Anyone knows why??

---

update@2015.01.15. Problem still persists. I have various Windows Services turned off that could be a potential cause as well. But since it still works with command window to import and I only need to do this very rarely, I've kinda put this behind and moved on. Still nice if someone can point out the exact cause..

Comment: btw i was able to import settings via the command window, Tools.ImportandExportSettings /import:filename

Comment: where did you run the command line from ?

Comment: Experience the same issue.  Ctrl+Alt+A - to switch to Command window.  Then enter Tools.ImportandExportSettings /import:"path to the settings file.vssettings". Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241277.aspx for details.

Answer (score 7):

### UPDATE: This still works in VS2017! (v15.8.8)

---

Sadly, this is a 2013 bug. I was able to successfully import my settings from VS2012 using the steps @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241277.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Using Ctrl+Alt+A to get the command window use the following syntax:

```
Tools.ImportandExportSettings [/export:filename | /import:filename | /reset]
```

example:

```
Tools.ImportandExportSettings /import:"C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Settings\MyFile.vssettings"
```

My 2013 version specifics:
[image: My 2013 version specifics]

Comment: This helped me to change my theme. Was annoying the hell out of me when I tried doing it through the menu but the Command Window method is a good way to change the Theme. Also, it gives intellisense so it is easier to type than in a command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the error msg instructions.  Using SSMS v17.7, I selected TOOLS, OPTIONS, Import and Export Settings -- Automatically save my settings to this file:

then entered my personal HOME directory at my company and included the provided file name: NewSettings.vssettings

Worked fine.