# How to DISABLE prompt: 'We've noticed that extension is slowing Visual Studio'

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Today I am gonna ask about something and lets hope it is not another one of my [unsolvable questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060301/vs-2015-import-and-export-settings-disappearing-window) this time :). In theory what I want to achieve is quite simple:

How do I disable this prompt in Visual Studio 2017? (CLARIFICATION: I know what is slowing down my Visual Studio, I don't care, I want to disable the PROMPT)

> We've noticed that extension '[extension name]' is slowing Visual Studio

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you click on the blue **Manage Visual Studio Performance** link (in your case **Zarzadzanie...**), Visual Studio should stop this notification.

Comment: Don't worry about my localization, it really is enough if you point out english equivalent. Thank you, but as far as I know in "Manage VS Performance" there is only option to disable certain extensions and not the prompt itself (Unless I am missing something).

Comment: @rvnlord There is no need to do anything in the dialog itself - just clicking on the link is enough to let VS know you've got the message. Actually, in my testing just clicking 'x' in enough for VS to stop showing the bar. I'm testing with one slow extension in VS 15.2 (26430.13). Maybe you have multiple slow extensions?